# How would I click this href link in Selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is the code:

```
<div class="padding">
      <a href="javascript:FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay()">
            <img alt="Example" src="http://freshco.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/week-flyer-left.jpg" height="158" width="280">
      </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to click on the href. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//href[text()='javascript:FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay']")).click();
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it does not work_? Do you get an error? Does nothing happen at all?

Comment: `href` is not a tag, but attribute.

Comment: It throws org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript:FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay']")).click();
```

Intead of:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//href[text()='javascript:FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay']")).click();
```

Comment: This gave me this error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='javascript:FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay']"}

Comment: May you may have one more element with same href. Can you post parent tag's of this Html code.

Comment: //img[@alt='Example']. Once try this.

Comment: It is because she forgot to attach the `()` at the end of the xpath expression. Or you can use this: "//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay')]"

Answer (score 0):

As another variant:

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("a[href*='FreshCoShowEFlyerOverlay']")).click();
```